# JQuery Ajax Content Loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink

I am using this script to load most of the pages in #content. I was wondering how should I go about enabling and disabling certain links from being affected. The problem is, on some pages I want the script to affect my main menu links completely, and on others, I want it to affect my menu partially so that I can load other pages and sub-domains.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('login.php')
    $(document).on('click','a',function()  {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('' + page + '.php')
        return false;
    });
});
```

So should I simply work with `$(document).on('click','a',function()  {?` to handle this? Is there a way to use a class tag to disable links from being affected? Or perhaps a better way to go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the links you don't want affected a class then exclude the class in your selector

```
<a href="..." class="noajax">...</a>

$(document).on('click','a:not(.noajax)',function()  {
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the event handler like:

```
$("a:not('.some-class')").click(function() {
  // etc.
});
```